Open google maps to directions using expo react-native-map-link for Android
This has had me scratching my head for a few weeks now. I have button on a page that allows the user to open the Google Maps app to directions from their current location to a new destination. The button works, opens google maps but it immediately closes leaving the user on the home screen. I've tried multiple ways of doing this with little success. I have tried using Linking and the react-native-map-link library.
The documentation  for the library states to add the library to plugins which I have done like so:
  "expo": {
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-location",
        {
          "locationAlwaysAndWhenInUsePermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to use your location."
        }
      ],
      ["react-native-map-link"]
    ],

And then call the functionality like this:
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.directionButtton}
          onPress={() => showLocation({
              latitude: venueLatitude,
              longitude: venueLongitude,
              sourceLatitude: location.coords.latitude,  // optionally specify starting location for directions
              sourceLongitude: location.coords.longitude,  // not optional if sourceLatitude is specified
              title: venueName,  // optional
              googleForceLatLon: false,  // optionally force GoogleMaps to use the latlon for the query instead of the title
              cancelText: 'Cancel', // optional (default: 'Cancel')
              directionsMode: 'car' // optional, accepted values are 'car', 'walk', 'public-transport' or 'bike'
          })}>
          <Text style={styles.venueButtonText}>DIRECTIONS</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

I have also tried adding the intent to use google maps to the android manifest using the suggest plugin script like this:

const withAndroidQueries = config => {
  return withAndroidManifest(config, config => {
    config.modResults.manifest.queries = [
      {
        intent: [
          {
            action: [{ $: { 'android:name': 'com.google.android.apps.maps.ACTION_VIEW' } }]
          },
        ],
      },
    ];

    return config;
  });
};

module.exports = withAndroidQueries;

Am I missing a step somewhere?

Are you able to provide a full demo?
